# What does rep movsd do in the context of this binary bomb phase?

Tags: c, x86, binary

I've been looking at this for hours with no progress. I need help understanding the overall idea of what's going on in this phase. From my research, I have a limited idea about what rep movsd does, but it's context is beyond me.

```
80492b9:    push ebp
80492ba:    mov ebp, esp
80492bc:    push edi
80492bd:    push esi
80492be:    push ebx
80492bf:    sub esp, 0xac
80492c5:    lea eax, [ebp+0xffffff70]
80492cb:    mov ebx, 0x804a0a0
80492d0:    mov edx, 0x1a
80492d5:    mov edi, eax
80492d7:    mov esi, ebx
80492d9:    mov ecx, edx
80492db:    rep movsd 
80492dd:    mov ecx, 0x0
80492e2:    mov eax, 0x20
80492e7:    and eax, 0xfffffffc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like a loop copying an array of `int`s.

- `ecx` is the number of `int`s to move.
- `esi` is the pointer to the start of the source array.
- `edi` is the pointer to the start of the destination array.

Comment: Would it be moving an array of 26 numbers? 8 values of 26? I ask because the bomb phase I know is expecting an input of 8 numbers...

Comment: @EdwardParrishMiller It would be moving 26 `int`s from one array to another.